# CSS Selector for selection only links that have images

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to have a such selector for css? I have a lightbox which I have to configure with css selectors and I only want to work with links that have imgs...

Comment: Only if the links have inline styles like `<a href="" style="background-image: url(foo);"></a>` then you can use `a[style*="background-image: url(foo);"]{...}`

Comment: Do you mean something like <a><img></a>? That is not possible with CSS.

Comment: No, It's **not** possible. Because there's no parent selector in CSS (yet) and also `:empty` wont target elements containing text nodes.

Comment: Lets see some HTML, it is impossible to tell you for sure if this is possible or not otherwise.

Comment: Would it not work to target the images inside links? What type of styling are you proposing to apply?

Comment: Can't you check your links for `<img` with jQuery or Javascript, and then add a class that you can style in CSS? In pseudocode: `If <a> contains <img, add class "link_with_image"`

Comment: well I have a lightbox where I have to enter a css selector for links which on click will be shown a lightbox. Cannot change anything else. But if I have normal links, it opens lightbox as well, not opening the websites, because the selector I have is " p a "